# SQL syntax error MySQL

Tags: mysql

I tried to create table in mysql command line on ubuntu.
This is code from book "Oracle Database 12c":

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    dob DATE,
    phone VARCHAR2(12)
);
```

I got an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    last_na' at line 2
```

Comment: MySQL and Oracle Server are two _completely different_ database engines. If you want to work with MySQL, read MySQL books/resources.

Comment: @Mat - Better: If you want to read Oracle books/resources, install a free copy of Oracle Database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish can be found below. You should be using data types that are supported by MySQL. Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html).

```
CREATE TABLE customers
( 
  customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(10),
  dob DATE,
  phone VARCHAR(12),
  zip_code VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

Comment: Do you know any simple tutorial how to install oracle db 12c on ubuntu?

Comment: [Try this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470349/installing-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-14-04). Your mileage may vary due to the ubuntu version, but it should be similar. You can also try 'install oracle db 12c on "ubuntu"' using Google search.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 12c Installation  in Ubuntu 16.04 refer 
[Install Oracle 12c in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/)  and to install Oracle 12c in Ubuntu 16.04.2  refer [Install Oracle 12 in different versions of Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191928/8042428) tested for Ubuntu 16.04.2