# Oracle 12c Ubuntu 17.04 Installation error

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Oracle 12c database on Ubuntu 17.04, but I get error ORA-27104:

[image]

My `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
#Added for fresh Oracle 12cR1 Installation
kernel.sem = 250        32000   100     128
# Assumes all of a 5120MB RAM is allocated, using 4K pages
kernel.shmall=8388608 # (=32*1024*1024*1024 / 4096) - 4096 is page size
# Assumes half of a 5120MB RAM is allocated, in bytes 
kernel.shmmax=34359738368 # (=32*1024*1024*1024), 
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.panic_on_oops = 1
fs.file-max = 6815744
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default = 262144
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 262144
net.core.wmem_max = 1048576
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
```

[image]

Any idea what may help to fix this?

Comment: Oracle does not support Ubuntu, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35855_01/artrt/docs12c/rtinst/pdsapp_A.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Or perhaps [ubuntu.se]. Apparently this question is too old to migrate. I suggest you delete it and post on a more relevant site.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the Oracle docs you would see that  Oracle doesnt support Ubuntu, 
I used a hack around as mentioned in the [Install Oracle 12c in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/) . The document and the script is originally written for installation of Oracle 12c in Ubuntu 16.04.The script had to be tweaked a bit to install Oracle 12c(version 12.1.0.2.0) in Ubuntu 16.04.2.

I downloaded the script [mandela.sh](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AL1G4tLE8F3dgsQ&cid=8C51C47ADD8D1B71&id=8C51C47ADD8D1B71%2122250&parId=8C51C47ADD8D1B71%2122249&o=OneUp) and made the below 2 changes to script and followed the instructions as is in [Install Oracle 12c in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/) .

1. Change line 81 `ver=16.04`  to `ver=16.04.2`
2. Change line 122 `if [ "$VERCHECK" != "Description:  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" ]; then` to `if [ "$VERCHECK" != "Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS" ]; then`

Make sure in step 2 give the Description as is given in the output of command 
`lsb_release -a`

Try your luck on Ubuntu 17.04 with above steps.